# autohotkey remap surface volume button

Tags: button, autohotkey, volume, surface

I have a surface pro 4 but the physical buttons has a hardware problem where the buttons press them self or when you move or touch the corner of the screen.

I was hoping to remap the buttons to "nothing" but it seems to be remapped to Shift, Ctrl, Alt.

Am i missing something?

Here is the code:

```
#SingleInstance, 
Force SetBatchLines, -1
SC130::
SC12E::
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that the entire code?
Since there is no return, it's going to continue on with the script. In other words, if I wanted AHK to type "help" anytime I pressed "y" or "e", I could do this:

```
y::
e::
SendInput help
return
```

Try changing the hotkey to something like this and see if it makes a difference:

```
SC130::Return
SC12E::Return
```